# Setting a DialFunc for pgxpool.Config

Tags: postgresql, go, ssh-tunnel, pgx

I am having trouble creating a connection to a postgres database via ssh tunneling with the "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool" library. I cannot seem to figure out how to set the DialFunc for the *pgxpool.Config that I would like to use to establish a connection. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
        sshConnStr := mkPostgresXViaSSHConnStr(config, tz)
        
        config, err := parseSshConnStr(sshConnStr)
        // var config *pgsshConfig

        sshcon, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", config.tunnelHost, config.tunnelConfig), &config.tunnelConfig)
        // var sshcon *ssh.Client

        cfg, err = pgxpool.ParseConfig(config.pgConnStr)
        // var cfg *pgxpool.Config

        cfg.ConnConfig.DialFunc = func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return sshcon.Dial(network, addr)
        }
```

When I try to set the DialFunc I get the following error: **cannot use (func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) literal) (value of type func(network string, addr string) (net.Conn, error)) as pgconn.DialFunc value in assignment**

Any suggestions about how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add context and cast to `pgconn.DialFunc`:

```
package main

import (
        "context"
        "net"

        "github.com/jackc/pgconn"
        "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool"
)

func main() {
        cfg, _ := pgxpool.ParseConfig("")
        myDial := func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
                return nil, nil
        }
        cfg.ConnConfig.DialFunc = pgconn.DialFunc(myDial)
}
```

Comment: I get two strange errors when I do that. The first: `DialFunc not declared by package pgx` even though I can see that it is.... and if I try to convert it to pgconn.DialFunc: `cfg.ConnConfig.DialFunc = pgconn.DialFunc(myDeal)` I get this error: `cannot convert myDeal (variable of type func(network string, addr string) (net.Conn, error)) to pgconn.DialFunc1`

Comment: @user17976520 sorry, used wrong import. Fixed now.

Comment: Is the casting necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the wrong type for the DialFunc. For pgx/v3.6.2 only the network and address were needed as parameters. In the updated version, pgx/v4 context.Context needs to be passed as a variable as well (whether or not it is actually used). The update which fixed the error is this:

```
cfg.ConnConfig.DialFunc = func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return sshcon.Dial(network, addr)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).